# SSRS Export to CSV oddity

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a report created with a row above the header and a footer.  It is treating the row above the header as a seperate column as well as the footer and adding this row over and over for each row.

I need one line as the first line of my CSV file (not to be repeated) and the same for the footer and all of the data inbetween those two lines.

I have tried to take them out of the table and put them into seperate text boxes but this has the same result.

As you can see in the CSV image it treats the HD and TR lines as rows.  The HD line should be at the top once only.  The TR line should be at the bottom once only.

[image: This is what my layout page looks like]

[image: This is the CSV]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected, and by design. CSV (and XML) exports are designed to be very generic data preserving formats. They include any dynamic data in the report as a field. All fields will be listed in the header row, where the field name is the name of the text box in the report.

If you need custom formatting such as a header row with report totals, or date of execution,  then SSRS CSV export is probably not for you. I'd look at SSIS or writing a custom export  application(.exe.) Or you could look at using one of the other export formats from SSRS.

Comment: You bring sad news to me.  Thank you for the info.