# How to avoid duplication of headers when exporting CSV from SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012

I'm trying to export .csv from SQL Server Reporting Services 2012.

The output is like:

[image]

I want output like:

```
Header1 Header2
Data1   Data2
Data3   Data4
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: from SQL Server? or from SSRS? The former implies SS**M**S. Which is it?

Comment: it's export from SSRS

Comment: and yet you didn't show how the source report is laid out, which will intimately affect what CSV it generates... is it a tablix? matrix? what row/column headers does it have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS Export to CSV oddity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551121/ssrs-export-to-csv-oddity)